# TypeError: function missing required positional argument when reading arguments from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I pass in variable values that are defined in a JSON file?

I have these two functions:

```
def fun1(a , b) : 
    print(a , b)

def fun2(c , d) : 
    print(c , d)


jsonfile = {    
    'function1' : {
        'callback' : 'fun1' , 
        'args' : ['a' , 'b']
    }, 
    'function2' : {
        'callback' : 'fun2',
        'args' : ['c' , 'd']
    }
}

# iter the json file looking for the function callback + the args to call them ..
for key , value in jsonfile.items() :
    function_name = value['callback']
    function_args = value['args']
    locals()[function_name](# how to pass the functions args ?? )
```

When I do:

```
locals()[function_name](function_args)
```

I get the following error, because the function thinks that I am passing only 1 argument, not 2:

```
   locals()[function_name](function_args)
TypeError: fun1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the `*` operator? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Shouldn't it be `globals()`? It doesn't make a difference outside a function, but if you move the code inside a function it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of arguments should be unpacked:

```
locals()[function_name](*function_args)
```

Comment: thanks. but how is possiable to convert these unpacked to variables. something like that 
a= 'var1'
b = 'var2'

so the  print output be 
var1
var2

Comment: If you change the json format to `'args' : {'a': 'var1' , 'b': 'var2'}` you can unpack with two asterisk like `[function_name](**function_args)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unpacking operator on `function_args`:

```py
for key , value in jsonfile.items() :
    function_name = value['callback']
    function_args = value['args']
    locals()[function_name](*function_args)
```

This outputs:

```py
a b
c d
```

Comment: beat me to it. I was about to say the list is being passed into the function as a single argument and needs to be unpacked

Comment: thanks. but how is possiable to convert these unpacked to variables. something like that a= 'var1' b = 'var2' so the print output be var1 var2

Comment: `a, b = <list to unpack>`